# RSpec "Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace" On every test

Tags: ruby, rspec, rbenv

I am working through some Ruby problem sets. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, rbenv 0.4.0-98-g13a474c, rspec 3.1.4, and ruby 2.0.0p353. I'm running into the following errors for every test I run and I'm hoping someone might be able to guide me in the right direction to a solution.

I have run rspec tests successfully in the past but I can't seem to figure out the issue with my current setup.

Here is the message I receive for every test I run:

```
 6) age is an integer
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
 # /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/mocks.rb:10:in `setup'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/mocking_adapters/rspec.rb:19:in `setup_mocks_for_rspec'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:366:in `run_before_example'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:150:in `block in run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:328:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:148:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:500:in `block in run_examples'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:496:in `map'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:496:in `run_examples'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:463:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `map'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block in run_specs'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:53:in `report'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:107:in `run_specs'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 # /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
 # /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
 # 
 #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
 #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
 #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
```

Edit: Here is an example of one of the spec files, however, the issue comes up on about 20 spec files. I know my solutions are correct and my peers aren't having the same issues I am:

```
first_name = "M"
last_name = "R"
age = 23

describe 'first_name' do
  it "is defined as a local variable" do
    expect(defined?(first_name)).to eq 'local-variable'
  end

  it "is a String" do
    expect(first_name).to be_a String
  end
end

describe 'last_name' do
  it "is defined as a local variable" do
    expect(defined?(last_name)).to eq 'local-variable'
  end

  it "be a String" do
    expect(last_name).to be_a String
  end
end

describe 'age' do
  it "is defined as a local variable" do
    expect(defined?(age)).to eq 'local-variable'
  end

  it "is an integer" do
     expect(age).to be_a Fixnum
  end
end
```

Comment: Add the spec file that is giving you the error.

Comment: Just added the spec file.

Comment: What is this? ``require_relative "my_solution"``

Comment: The error you posted doesn't match the spec file you posted. ``6) age is an integer``. And there is no age expectation in your file.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I copy and pasted one from another challenge on accident, since they all have been giving me the same error. Updated it, though.

Comment: I believe the require_relative "my_solution" tells the file to look for the solution in the my_solution.rb file, but again, I'm not sure and a novice in this area. The spec file was given to me for a class and I was supposed to put the solution in the my_solution.rb file and then run the spec file to test.

Comment: Found the problem. I had installed rspec with "sudo apt-get" instead of gem install. Not sure the reason why that was an issue, however.

Comment: Rspec with apt-get? Wow. I didnt even know that was an option.

Comment: The solution should be posted as an answer.